# How can i remove specific element from struct object array in solidity

Tags: solidity

> Solidity: **Here I want to remove specific email from struct object string array.How can i do that in solidity.**
> **Advance Thanks.**

```
 struct Users{
        string fullname;
        string[] email;
    }
mapping(address => Users) private userinfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the `address` of the user and the order of emails doesn't matter, this could be a way:

```
    struct Users{
       string fullname;
       string[] email;
    }
    mapping(address => Users) private userinfo;

    function compareString(string memory str1, string memory str2) internal returns (bool) {
        if(bytes(str1).length != bytes(str2).length) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(str1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(str2));
        }
    }

    function removeEmail(address userAddress, string memory emailToRemove) external {
        string[] memory emails = userinfo[userAddress].email;
        uint256 emailLength = emails.length;
        for (uint256 i; i<emailLength; i++) {
            if (compareString(emails[i], emailToRemove)) {
                userinfo[userAddress].email[i] = userinfo[userAddress].email[emailLength - 1];
                userinfo[userAddress].email.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
delete userinfo[address].email[index];
```

So, by using this you can remove your element from array.
But there is one more problem will arise, when you delete this particular element from array then that index's value will remove but still there exist a blank space.

So, you need to switch it with the last element of an array then use pop().